# Repeat texture many times

Tags: glsl, webgl, textures, texture-mapping

I'm drawing my lines filled with a texture i'm repeating in my shader. As show below

[image]

The line are single points - that each vertex i'm expanding in my vertex shader with some calculation that always will be same pixel width no matter what zoom we are.

[image]

Than i'm creating my triangles and on them i'm drawing my texture repeatedly on the X axis. so the width of the line is always the image height.

The user can zoom in as much as he wants and the shapes getting bigger and smaller as zoom change. Although the texture saving it's size, means that there are more repeats.

When the user zoom in very much i'm starting to get strange results, i guess due to float overflow.

zoom:1

[image]

zoom 2

[image]

My shaders:

**Vertex Shader**

```
uniform float factor;
attribute vec2 texCoords;
varying vec2 vTexCoords;
attribute vec4 texAtlas;
varying vec4 vTexAtlas;
uniform vec4 uPixelWolrdScale;
attribute vec2 outlineOffset;
 
void main() {
   vTexCoords = texCoords;
   vTexAtlas = texAtlas;
   gl_Position = LIGHTGLgl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * (LIGHTGLgl_Vertex + uWorldOffset) + vec4((outlineOffset.xy) * uPixelWolrdScale.zw, 0,0);
}
```

uPixelWolrdScale is vec4 with the xy = worldScale.xy / ScreenSize.xy, zw = 2/ ScreenSize.xy.

I'm using the `zw` for offseting the width of the line
and the xy for repeating my texture in the fragment shader

```
precision highp float;
uniform float factor;
uniform vec4 color;
varying vec2 vTexCoords;
uniform vec4 uPixelWolrdScale;
uniform sampler2D sampler;
varying vec4 vTexAtlas;

void main() {

   // Here is the problem i guess
   vec2 vexelPos = fract(vec2((vTexCoords.s) / (uPixelWolrdScale.x * factor), vTexCoords.t));
   vexelPos = vTexAtlas.xy + vexelPos * vTexAtlas.zw;
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler, vexelPos);
   gl_FragColor *= color;

}
```

`vTexCoords.s` is the number of the repeats when the world and the screen is the same units. no zoom.

Is there another way to repeat the texture when `(vTexCoords.s) / (uPixelWolrdScale.x * factor)` is overflowing?

**-----EDITED ------**

Tried to change my approach by using `mod()` instead of `fract()` for achieving repeats.

After few rounds I've managed to do this, as solution to my problem, but it is still in some zooms starting to freak.

The basic thought is to use homogeneous values for repeating the texture with a additional computing varying - with the help of the texture size and modulus.

**In my vertex shader**

I've added attribute and varying

```
attribute vec4 startVertex;
varying float vVertex;
...
// Same calculation i did to the gl_Vertex I do here to the attribute
vec4 coordToRemove = LIGHTGLgl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * (startVertex + uWorldOffset) + vec4((outlineOffset.xy) * uPixelWolrdScale.zw, 0,0);
vVertex = gl_Position.x - coordToRemove.x;
```

I want my varying to start from 0 and interpolate all the way to the second homogeneous position. so I've added the first vertex value as an attribute for both vertices - `coordForVar`- So when the first vertex will get here `vVertex` will be 0. and the second `vVertex` will be the difference.

**In my fragment shader**

```
varying float vVertex;
...
float hmgSize = 1. / 32.; // Getting the size in homogeneous - For now 32px, later uniform/attribute
vec2 vexelPos = vec2(mod(vVertex, hmgSize) / hmgSize, vTexCoords.t);
vexelPos = vTexAtlas.xy + vexelPos * vTexAtlas.zw;
```

Comment: I've not managed to fully understand you, but `vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy/resolution;` gives you accurate pixel size, if it could help...(resolution is texture size)

Comment: @j-p `resolution` is not part of WebGL itself, just some common environments. `uPixelWolrdScale` is doing almost the same job here.

Comment: resolution is (Tex Width, tex Height).

Comment: Is that really your fragment shader? It's missing a `#version ...` directive (optional) and a `precision ... float` statement (not optional in fragment shaders). I'd go with `mediump` though chances are it will make no difference whatsoever in your typical WebGL implementation (most desktop hardware doesn't care about this).

Comment: There is a `precision highp float` but it is not helping. Edited my post now. my `vTexAtlas` is the location (xy) and size (zw) of my texture inside a texture atlas. but this is not my problem. The problem is that dividing my `(vTexCoords.s/uPixelWolrdScale.x)` creates float overflow number which causes wrong drawing. I'm using LightGL, very simple WebGL library for getting more power

Comment: Can you give examples of values for vTexCoords.s and uPixelWorldScale.x? How are the 2 values changing when you zoom? (do they become smaller, bigger?)

Comment: When adding the shape vertices to the buffer i'm calculating how many times the size of my picture fits along the the shape when my zoom 1:1 - which mean `uPixelWorldScale.x = 1`. And `vTexCoords.s` is this number of the repeats.. can be 10 or 1000 depends on the image size and the size of the shape. When we zoom in this `vTexCoords.s` is divided by `uPixelWorldScale.x` That getting smaller and smaller, such as 0.1->0.00001 depends of the zoom. which causes my shader divide (100/0.00001)=10000000 which basically this is the number of the texture repeat in this zoom, but then we see the result

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman in opengl, version is like super important, but I wouldn't recommend to use version directive within webgl1 shader. Also I would recommend to use `precision highp float`, because for example ipad with `precision medium float` wont handle ashima simplex noise 2d, or at least remember this well "

Comment: @EntityBlack: Support for `precision highp float` is not guaranteed in fragment shaders in OpenGL ES 2.0 (WebGL). You would have to do some pre-processor tests to use it compliantly, but ES 2.0 _does_ guarantee `mediump` support so it's a good universal choice. Version, on the other hand, is completely optional and automatically assumed to be **100** by default in ES 2.0. There is no default floating-point precision in a fragment shader, which is why it's required.

Comment: No problem.. I've just removed the many uniform the `lightgL` library is adding to my shaders. and i guess i removed the precision line as well

Comment: I've added some way to solve the problem, and there for sure we don't have overflow. But still the drawing is not correct

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Information about precision support was very valuable in few past days. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using fract and mod in texture coordinates can do weird things with mipmapping, make sure your texture is using Nearest Filtering for min and mag filters and go from there

---

*Edit:*

Regardless what the contents of your texture is texture2D is only really looking up texture coordinates between 0 and 1. The integer portion is for repeats but using it reduces precision on the lookup. Using fract or mod to do the repeat rather than the integer portion can cause a 1px discontinuity in mipmap lookup; but if you are altasing you will have that issue anyway.

So your lookup for an atlas your texture coords should be a range that is a fraction of 0..1

For example a range of 0.0625 if you had 16x16 images. e.g. 3rd texture in X is 0.125 to 0.1875.

You want to deal with the repeats outside the texture coords, then convert the value to that range.

---

*Edit:*

When zoomed in rather than making your geometry a million units long, but only showing one millionth of it; which is just causing precision fighting, make your geometry screen sized; then you should have all the precision you need.

For example after doing your perspective calc your geometry x,y coordinates will be in screen space and only displayed where they are in the box -1,-1 to 1,1. At this point you can intersect and trim (or discard/ignore) the geometry so the x,y is in that box then set your texture varying to be the number of screen repeats matching what it should be. This will mean it doesn't need the precision of fractions of a million.

Comment: They don't have nearest for filter, but this is not my problem here. it's the shifting in the vexel when numbers are big/low

Comment: Ok, change: gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler, vexelPos); to gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler, fract(vexelPos)); to see if you have issues in the post multiplication

Comment: Tried.. not fixing it.. Just for making it clear, I'm using a texture atlas, so my sub texture cycle is not 0-1 like `fract` does. This is why in my code you can find this line `vexelPos = vTexAtlas.xy + vexelPos * vTexAtlas.zw;` (`xy` is the location and `zw` is the size) when the input `vexelPos` is value 0 to 1 value and the new value after this line will be the value in the texture atlas

Comment: Didn't quite understand you. When I want to repeat the 3rd image on 16x16 images atlas, let's say, 1000 times. What should I send as attribute, and how I get my vexed? Just to make it clear. My vTexAtlas are in fraction range.

Comment: Adjust the coords by the repeats then drop the integer portion so repeating 1000 times in x and 1 time in y would be something like: vec2 vexelPos = fract(vTexCoords * vec2(1000.0,1.0)); then shrink by altas size  vexelPos *= 1.0 / vec2(16.0,16.0); then offset by position vexelPos += vec2(2.0,0.0) / vec2(16.0,16.0);

Comment: Changed `vTexCoords` to 0-1 values and set my repeat as constant attribute. but unfortunately I get exactly the same results.. The problem in my case that because of the zoom-in the repeats count is changing to big numbers. When we zoom-out we can have 10 repeats. When we zoomed in we can get 2 million repeats. and there is my problem.

Comment: ok, you'll have a problem; can you come at it from a different approach and absorb some of the precision in the coordinates. So when zoomed in rather than making your geometry a million units long, but only showing one millionth of it; which is just causing precision fighting, make your geometry screen sized; then you should have all the precision you need.

Comment: I have allot of geometries, allot of data that being added once (of course). Changing it every zoom (or every few zooms) and calculating the containing part of the geometries it is not really working for me. Or by `make your geometry screen sized` you mean something else? What I tried before is to cut the geometry segments to allot of small segments - in the insert time. But in some zoom the texture still freaking, so i dropped this solution..

Comment: Meant in vertex shader, anyway for the integer portion which defines repeats your max values/repeats are between 16384 and 128 depending on hardware: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876(v=vs.85).aspx so you need to absorb that elsewhere before using it in texture coordinates

Comment: But when i'm doing the repeat by myself in the shader and not using the `wrap_s/t=REPEAT` this limitation is irrelevant. Doesn't it ?

Comment: Yes but then only the values between 0->1 are important to the coordinates. Will put an edit in answer to describe what I meant by coord changing

Comment: So basically what you suggest is to perform an intersection of the geometries in the homogeneous unit (in the shader) with the screen `-1 to 1 values` ? which mean that i need to send for each segment its other side vertex as attribute in order to have a line, and this line to cut and change the output vertex. correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Don't need to add more, the texture coords attribute already tell you about line (0->1 e.g. start vs end)

Comment: Yes, but when there 2 vertex creating a line.. and for each vertex i need to find the intersection with the screen. For finding this intersection I need to know the angle of the line - and this by having the other vertex.